# How to load external page content into current page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running this bit, where basically I want to load part of an external page content into current page using `.load()`

JS

```
$(".rounded-circle").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).next("span").data("gal") + " .carousel";
  console.log(url);
  $(".gallery").load(url);
});
```

`var url` gives: `http:/example.com/mypage.php .carousel`

`mypage.php` does have a content within a class `.carousel`

But the above gives:

> jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http:/example.com/mypage.php .carousel

This works:

```
$(".galleria").load("http:/example.com/mypage.php");
```

But I only want to get content of the external page within `.carousel` and not the whole page.

Comment: Try to wrap your `.carousel` content into a div with `id` attribute since all the examples in the documentation used an `id` not a class

Comment: Try hard coded `$(".galleria").load("http:/example.com/mypage.php  .carousel");` then if that works debug the `data()` version

Comment: @charlietfl nope, that won't work. Already tried. It is working tho wrapping the content with an ID as per previous comment, but I remember I used a class and it worked in the past

Comment: @AmrAly well yeah, that seems to work

Comment: they should have mentioned it in the docs.

Comment: Basics work fine here using class as selector in url string http://plnkr.co/edit/wKJkwS1uLH3SwoNEdMrf?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl really don't know why, what version of jQuery is it using?

Comment: v 3.2.1...change to 3.3.1(your version) and works the same

Comment: @charlietfl ehmm, i try again, but tbh i don't mind using an id as it works. Thanks tho

Comment: Why you `+ " .carousel"`? I guess you should remove this.

Comment: @TanDuong because I don't want to load the whole page but only part of it.

Comment: @TanDuong because `load()` allows for selector to filter with. Read the docs

Comment: But `http:/example.com/mypage.php .carousel` is invalid url. I think you want to `$(".gallery").find('.carousel').load(url);`

Comment: Ah. I just read the `load()` document. I out updated for a long time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am providing a working answer in order not to leave blank. Eventually I have wrapped the content I want to load within a `div` with an `ID` and it works. Yet one of the comment demonstrated that it should also work with a `class`, but in my case wasn't and since I don't mind the other solution, I leave it like that, so...

**Note**: I have also changed the way I was getting the `url` and I now grab it from the `href` directly.

```
$(".galLInk").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = this.href + " #galleriaSingle";
  console.log(url);
  $(".galleria").load(url);
});
```